# how to solve cppdb/frontend.h compilation error

Tags: c++, makefile

I am extending a project which includes cppdb/frontend.h, but when I compile I always have this compilation error.

```
graph_from_db.cpp:6:28: fatal error: cppdb/frontend.h: No such file or directory
  #include <cppdb/frontend.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
```

I tried to install libcppdb0 in my Kubuntu 14.04 but it gives this error

> E: Package 'libcppdb0' has no installation candidate.

What could be the best way to include this package or file to the project?
I am using a 32bit HP computer with i386 architecture. I have been on this for two weeks now no solution.

Comment: I believe the package you're looking for is called `libcppdb-dev`.

Comment: i couldn't install libcppdb-dev because it couldn't find the package, but i tried to download it and install it. i also tried to download cppdb-0.3.1 library to add it but it still has the same error. i followed this instruction, download cppdb[1], unpack it, go in the directory, and
execute:
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ mkdir ~/lib
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=`readlink -e ~/lib` ..
$ make
After try to execute this
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH":~/lib